# How is hexadecimal data from navigation be translated (i ues pixhawk and arduino)? can i get longitude and latitude data from HEX file data?

Tags: navigation, gps, nmea, nmea2000

I wanna try to create a fake navigation data/format that will work for pixhawk and Mission Planner. I try sending  and receiving data with arduino. When the arduino received the response (i use navigation sensor from Ublox), it came with Hexadecimal number which i still dont understand. After googling Ublox's data sheet, it seems like it is some sort of structure or format for the data that is like a NMEA sentence (but it is difficult to learn, unlike a normal NMEA sentence). The example below from one of the response lines, are there longitude or latitude information?

```
first response:  b5 62 01 07 5c 00 a0 c0 6a 11 e7 07 07 0c 09 09 32 37 0b 00 00 00 1f 9b ad 2f 03 01 0a 0b 84 22 18 40 74 43 db fb 0d 18 0a 00 cc 11 0a 00 85 0e 00 00 9c 1f 00 00 fb ff ff ff 1c 01 00 00 54 fe ff ff 1c 01 00 00 1e 07 7e 00 c1 05 00 00 7b f1 39 00 a4 00 00 00 e0 4a 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 51
second response: b5 62 01 07 5c 00 68 c1 6a 11 e7 07 07 0c 09 09 33 37 0b 00 00 00 ff 92 fe ff 03 01 0a 0b 8c 22 18 40 77 43 db fb 8d 19 0a 00 4c 13 0a 00 84 0e 00 00 b0 1f 00 00 fe ff ff ff 3e 01 00 00 97 fd ff ff 3e 01 00 00 1e 07 7e 00 a2 06 00 00 0d f3 39 00 a4 00 00 00 e0 4a 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c7 a4
```

What i expect, is that i hope i can translate the navigation response. What i understand, it has header (b5 62) , class/ID (01 07) but idk what is this, payload, and checksum (last two digits). i wanna know why the number seems like has certain patterns, so the number seems repeating to me but it is also slightly differents with the previous data (like why the checksum, last two digits are the only numbers that always differ from previous data)